# Primeiro aplicativo: Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, x86

sou programado c# e preciso fazer um projeto pra android e pesquisando encontrei o xamarin... Fiz a instalação só que não estou conseguindo compilar o projeto... tanto no visual studio  quanto no Xamarin Studio dá o seguinte erro que não descobri como resolver...

> The package does not support the device architecture (x86). You can change the supported architectures in the Android Build section of the Project Options.
>
> Deployment failed. Architecture not supported.

Obrigado

Comment: Altere nas configurações de compilação do seu projeto para a arquitetura ARM, ao invés de x86, pois um dos assemblies que você esta linkando, aparentemente não suporta x86. Acredito que seja possível alterar para "Todas arquiteturas" também, mas não me lembro ao certo.

Answer (score 2):

Vá nas propriedades do projeto em seguida, vá em Android Options, clique na aba advanced e desmarque a opção x86.

[image: Configuraçãodo projeto Android]

Answer (score 0):

1. -De um duplo clique em `propriedades(properties)` na sua `solução(solution)`
2. -Na seção `Opções Android(Android options)` clique em `Avançado(advanced)`
3. -Escolha todas a opções de arquitetura disponível para melhor compatibilidade como mostrado na imagem
4. -De um `Rebuild all`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]